# How to read the data from three tables which is not having the same id

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, inner-join, cross-join

Hi i am using three table to display the customer order information

```
1. Order table(OrderId, ItemName, Description, etc...)
2. Order_Gas_Quantity(Order_gas_quantyID, OrderID, Quantity)
3. Customer_Supplying_Days(SupplyingID, CustID, SupplyingDays)
```

While saving customer data I'm saving the supplying days into `customer_Suppling_Days`, in this table I am using `CustID`.
Also, tables 1 & 2 have the same ID of `OrderID`.

I want to display the items which is ordered today and also supplying days. For example, while saving the customer data there is an option to select the days, if customer selecting needs it on Monday, Wednesday, Friday. So the application should generate the report for orders taken today and also item should supply on Friday.
This table structure for `customer_Suppling_Days`

```
`SupplyDayID    int Unchecked
CustID          int Checked
SupplyDays    nvarchar(50)  Checked
```

Table Structure for `Orders`

```
OrderID int Unchecked
Date    varchar(50) Checked
CName   varchar(50) Checked
CustId  int Checked
CLocation   varchar(50) Checked
Gas varchar(50) Checked
Quantity    varchar(50) Checked
VehicleNo   varchar(50) Checked
VehicleLocation varchar(50) Checked
Source  varchar(50) Checked
```

Table Structure For `Order_Gas_qty`

```
OrderGasQty int Unchecked
CustId  int Checked
GasName varchar(50) Checked
Quantity    varchar(50) Checked
OrderDate   varchar(50) Checked
CylinderNo  varchar(50) Checked
OrderId int Checked
```

Comment: 1. Post some sample data. 2. You should have a CustID in Order_Gas_Quantity

Comment: How is Order and Customer supplying information related?

Comment: what till i am trying writing two queries and merge them in gridview and displaying.,

Comment: Exactly, you didn't provide any information about the relationship between Customer_Supplying_Days and Order_table/Order_Gas_Quantity.

Comment: @sarvan, when merge two tables, you need a common attribute, such as calendar_date? order_id? etc

Comment: Ok is it like you want to display all orders placed today  along with every customer who can supply these orders today?

Comment: date is getting stored as varchar(), please share some sample data.. else what i suggest might not work becuase of incompatible date formats..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have stored dates in `varchar()` format which is **strongly not recomended**. Store dates in `Date` format only . In case you cannot change the table structure then simple inner join like following should work:

```
select O.OrderID,
O.Date,
O.CName,
O.Gas,
O.Quantity,
O.VehicleNo,
O.VehicleLocation,
O.[Source],
OGQ.CylinderNo
from Orders O
inner join Order_Gas_qty OGQ on OGQ.OrderId = O.OrderId
inner join Customer_Supplying_Days CSD on O.CustId = CSD.CustId
where O.Date = convert( varchar(20),getdate(),101) 
-- please change the format here as per your requirement
and SupplyDayID = Day(getdate())
-- this condition also depends on data in your table
```